# How do I retrieve image and text from firebase into recycle view?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Users are allowed to upload images and text to Firebase. I Would like to retrieve them and display it inside a recycler view. Some help on how i would do this would be appreciated.

I have already managed to save users image and text to Firebase, the only problem I'm having is actually retrieving it and displaying it inside recycler view, I have already set up my recycler view and created my Adapter class I am not sure where to go from here.

```
//saves user image and description inside Firebase 
public void saveToFirebase(){
    String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    userPost = new (selectedImageUri,descriptionEditText.getText().toString());
    postDictionary.put("PostImage", userPost.getImage().toString());
    postDictionary.put("Description", userPost.getDescription());
    productsDatabaseRef.child("Producuts").child(userId).push().setValue(postDictionary);
}

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Post> userPost;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> userPost){
        context = context;
        userPost = userPost;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.shop_layout_design,viewGroup, false));
    }

    //this is where you set the value for the ui elements
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.title.setText(userPost.get(i).getDescription());
        Picasso.get().load(userPost.get(i).getImage()).into(viewHolder.postImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userPost.size();
    }


    //links up ui elements
    class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        ImageView postImage;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: You will need then to get the data from database using ValueEventListener and onDataChange Callback which is in firebase database and then in the datasnapshot make sure you are getting the node you have added the data inside and then after you get the node where you have the list of items , retrieve this list and send it to the recyclerview as an arraylist of posts

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation. If you have a node group like this:

master/root (Firebase Database):

- item-1

  - picture-info: https://google.com/picture-url
  - name-info: "Google Log"

  ...

Then you will need to have a ValueEventListener added to your database class in your code. From there using the data snapshot you can do it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> info = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("item-1");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            info.put(childSnapshot.getKey(), childSnapshot.getValue().toString()); //Getting the information of each item.
        }

        InfoAdapter adapter = new InfoAdapter(stats); //Your adapter
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); //Setting the adapter
    }
}
```

Then you can parse the information in your adapter. By using a loop which increments by 2(because we have two info items in the arraylist on the same item from the database) you will be able to access the information by doing arraylist.get(i) and arraylist.get(i + 1).

You can even think of using a hashmap which would be more efficient. It depends on you. Hope it helps!